# Python: Functions used on each element of list x vs Functions that take list x as arg

Tags: python, function, list-comprehension

Is there any reason to choose one style over the other?
Example:

```
def add_10(x):
    return x + 10

results = [add_10(i) for i in range(5)]
```

VS

```
def add_10(list_):
   return [e + 10 for e in list_]

results = add_10(range(5))
```

This is a basic example, but it illustrates the idea.  I have been using the former recently because I just like writing functions with simple inputs and outputs (not that lists are complicated), but I don't know if there are any real pro's or con's to it other than personal style. I see more of the latter in documentation and other people's code, but I can't find any resources that address this specific idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version is more general, it can be used with values that are in any kind of data structure (or not in any structure, just a single variable). For instance, if you have a dictionary, you could use it to create a new dictionary where all the elements are increased by 10. Or you can write:

```
input_plus_10 = add_10(int(input("Please enter a number")))
```

The second version is more specific, it can only be used with lists. If that's the only thing you need, then it's fine (but you should name it something like `list_add_10`).

Comment: So it sounds like 6 of one half a dozen of the other?  Point taken though, on the specificity of the second version.

Comment: It's really a matter of overall modularity and what you need.